# cannot delete resource using either web console or shell

Tags: ibm-cloud

We are trying to remove services from a "pay-as-you-go" account.  However, we cannot.

We get an error saying try again from the GUI.  We simply get a message that the server is misbehaving from the ibmcloud shell (including when using `force` and `recursive` options).

How to delete this service?

```
cloudshell:~$ ibmcloud resource service-instance-delete -f --recursive error-deleting-service
Deleting service instance error-deleting-service in resource group default under account IBMER's Account as me@eworld.net...
FAILED
Delete "https://wasaas-broker.eu-de.websphereappsvr.cloud.ibm.com/wasaas-broker/broker/v2/service_instances/giant-long-string-with-bunch-of-%3A-that-may-be-uniquely-identifying-dunno&accepts_incomplete=true": Delete "https://wasaas-broker.eu-de.websphereappsvr.cloud.ibm.com/wasaas-broker/broker/v2/service_instances/giant-long-string-with-bunch-of-%3A-that-may-be-uniquely-identifying-dunno&accepts_incomplete=true": dial tcp: lookup wasaas-broker.eu-de.websphereappsvr.cloud.ibm.com on 10.10.10.10:53: server misbehaving

cloudshell:~$ ibmcloud resource service-instance error-deleting-service
Retrieving service instance error-deleting-service in resource group default under account IBMER's Account as me@eworld.net...
OK
                       
Name:                  error-deleting-service
ID:                    giant-long-string-with-bunch-of-:-that-may-be-uniquely-identifying
GUID:                  other-portion-of-giant-long-string-that-may-be-uniquely-identifying
Location:              eu-de
Service Name:          websphereappsvr
Service Plan Name:     waslibertycoreplan
Resource Group Name:   default
State:                 active
Type:                  service_instance
Sub Type:              
Locked:                false
Created at:            2020-01-29T03:52:10Z
Created by:            bananajr@bloomcounty.org
Updated at:            2022-12-23T06:27:41Z
Last Operation:                  
                       Status    delete failed
                       Message   Delete "https://wasaas-broker.eu-de.websphereappsvr.cloud.ibm.com/wasaas-broker/broker/v2/service_instances/giant-long-string-with-bunch-of-%3A-that-may-be-uniquely-identifying-dunno&accepts_incomplete=true": Delete "https://wasaas-broker.eu-de.websphereappsvr.cloud.ibm.com/wasaas-broker/broker/v2/service_instances/giant-long-string-with-bunch-of-%3A-that-may-be-uniquely-identifying-dunno&accepts_incomplete=true": dial tcp: lookup wasaas-broker.eu-de.websphereappsvr.cloud.ibm.com on 10.10.10.10:53: server misbehaving
```

Comment: What type of service is it? Is it a regular service from the IBM Cloud catalog? If the error persists, the best option is to contact support.

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to suggest a DNS failure (the give away is `dial tcp: lookup`). That is unusual given you are using the IBM Cloud Shell hosted CLI, as recommended by @data_henrik - contact Support should be the first go-to for strange behaviour like this.

It is best to check with Support, but it appears this service 'IBM WebSphere Application Server in IBM Cloud' was withdrawn and replaced by [IBM WebSphere Application Server for Virtual Servers](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/was-for-vsi). Therefore the API Endpoint would not exist any longer.

For future purposes, this is what I would recommend in sequence:

- ensure you are targeting the correct IBM Cloud Region from the IBM Cloud CLI, for example `ibmcloud target -r eu-de -g Default`. Not all services are available to access from Global level
- check whether the IBM Cloud CLI has a specific command to delete this resource, for example with VPC Infrastructure Services a specific command to delete a VPC Subnet would be `ibmcloud is subnet-delete`
- check the DNS Resolver used is able to reach the endpoint, for example `dig @1.1.1.1 +noall +answer +multiline A subdomain.domain.com`. Not applicable in your case as you are using the IBM Cloud Shell hosted CLI
- look for connected resources that may prevent the deletion of the service and the error message given at the service instance level may not be accurate, see below.
- brute force deletion of the resource instances, see below examples.

#### Look for connected resources within an IBM Cloud account, loop to export all resources from all resource groups

```bash
ibmcloud login --apikey=

rg_list=$(ibmcloud resource groups --output json | jq -r .[].name)

for i in $rg_list; do echo "$i" && \
ibmcloud resource service-instances --type all \
-g "$i" --output json \
| jq --arg rg_name "$i" \
--raw-output \
'["Resource Name","Resource CRN","Resource Type","Region","State","Type","Created At","Updated At","Last Operation Type","Last Operation Status","Last Operation Description","Resource Group ID","Resource Group Name"]
,
(.[] | [.name, .crn, .resource_id, .region_id, .state, .type, .created_at, .updated_at, .last_operation.type, .last_operation.state, .last_operation.description, .resource_group_id, $rg_name])
| @csv' > "resources_rg_$i.csv" \
; done

echo 'Created CSV for each IBM Cloud Resource Group, merging into single CSV also'
cat *.csv | uniq > resources_all.csv
echo 'Complete'
```

#### Example of brute force resources deletion

```bash
ibmcloud is instance-delete --force $INSTANCE_ID
ibmcloud is volume-delete --force $VOL_SHORT_ID
ibmcloud dns instance-delete $DNS_SHORT_ID
ibmcloud is vpc-delete $VPC_NAME
ibmcloud resource service-instance-delete --force $CRN_HERE
ibmcloud resource service-instance-delete --force --recursive $CRN_HERE
ibmcloud resource group-delete -f $RG_NAME
```